# Finding conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

This is Q6.46 of Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability:

> The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
>
> $f(x, y) = cxy^3$, $0 < x < 1$, $0 < y < x^{1/4}$
>
> Find $c$ and the conditional distribution of $X$, given $Y = y$

The first part (i.e, finding the normalising constant) was fine. The problem is finding the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = y$. My attempt follows below:

Given the joint, we know that the conditional density of X given $Y = y$ is

$$\frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
$$=\frac{12xy^3}{\int_{0}^{1} 12xy^3 dx}$$
$$=\frac{12xy^3}{|6x^2y^3|^1_0}$$
$$=\frac{12xy^3}{6y^3}$$
$$=2x$$

My confusion is on using this to find the cumulative distribution. My understanding is that I simply need to integrate this to get the CDF - but over what exactly? I was thinking from 0 to 1, but that ignores the $0 < y < x^{1/4}$ condition which I'm not sure how to use. And regardless, I don't get anywhere close to their answer:

$$\frac{2x}{1 - y^8}, y^4$$

and I don't understand why there are two answers either.

Answer (score 2):

You miscalculated the marginal of $Y$. To obtain the marginal of $Y$, we are interested in $y$ going between numerical values, but in the original path $y$ goes between functions, we must fix this in the following way
\begin{align*}
0 < y < x^{1/4} \Rightarrow y^{4} < x < 1 
\end{align*}
and we have $0 < y< 1$. You can draw a picture of this to find everything easier.So
$$
f_{Y}(y) = \int_{y^{4}}^{1} 12xy^3 dx = -6 y^3 (y^8-1), \quad 0<y<1
$$
substituting in the conditional formula
$$
f_{X|Y = y}(x) = \frac{12xy^3}{-6 y^3 (y^8-1)} = \frac{2x}{1-y^8}, \quad y^4 < x < 1
$$

Comment: Hi @daniel, thanks for the response, but aren't we finding the density function and not the distribution function in that case? I don't see you integrating over the density. 

(also: small typo in the last line - should be $12xy^3$ not $12xy^4$)

Comment: @Leaderboard ooh if you wanna calculate the cumulative , we have $F_{X|Y = y}(x) = \int_{y^4}^{x} \frac{2u}{1-y^8} du= \frac{x^2 - y^8}{1-y^8}$